# Xpage .component.setValue('Some Value') works on some xpage not on others

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

I'm setting value of input field on click event of the check  box. The editable field is used to validate group of check boxes. This code works in one xpage. When I tried to replicate this code in other xpage, it is not working.

Here is a working code:

```
    <xp:checkBox
        text="pH"
        id="checkBox1"
        value="#{document1.PH}"
        checkedValue="pH">
        <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="routineSectionInput1"
        execMode="partial">
            <xp:this.action>
                <xp:executeScript>
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var  
checkBox1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputCheckbox = getComponent("checkBox1");
    var routineSectionInput1:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText = getComponent("routineSectionInput1");
    if (checkBox1.getValue()=='pH'){
    routineSectionInput1.setValue('Selected');
    } else {
    routineSectionInput1.setValue('');
    }}]]></xp:this.script>
                                               </xp:executeScript>
            </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
            </xp:checkBox>
```

I used same field names and same code on another xpage and it is not working. What I'm doing wrong?

Best regards

Answer (score 5):

When you work with component logic where binding is involved, don't go after the component, go after the data that defines their value. So your code would rather look like this:

```
    <xp:checkBox text="pH" id="checkBox1"
    value="#{document1.PH}" checkedValue="pH">
    <xp:eventHandler
    event="onclick"
    submit="true"
    refreshMode="partial"
    refreshId="routineSectionInput1"
    execMode="partial">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:executeScript>
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var chkValue = document1.getItemValueString("PH");
                viewScope.routineSection = (chkValue=="pH") ? "Selected" : ""; 
            }]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:executeScript>
        </xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:checkBox>
        <xp:text id="routineSectionInput1" value="#{viewScope.routineSection}"></xp:text>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code on existing document and it is not allowing me to put the document in edit mode. For the new document, the value is not changed. Thanks again.

Comment: Mohan: that doesn't sound like a related problem. If you can't put a document into edit mode, you have to check your access rights (or database integrity)

Answer (score 1):

If there are validation errors or components have data that is of the wrong data type (e.g. text that cannot be parsed as a number in a component bound to a Number field, so conversion errors), any SSJS will fail.

I'd recommend adding a print statement at the start of the SSJS to check whether it's firing. (If you're more confident with XPages, use a PhaseListener to check the correct phase is being triggered).

Also, it's worth adding an Display Errors control to catch any validation errors caught during the partial refresh, ensuring it's within the refresh area (otherwise the errors will not be displayed in the browser).

"Process data without validation" option may be of use here, it you want to skip validation. Note that conversion errors will still prevent SSJS running.

As Stephan says, use the datasource rather than the component, if possible. The datasource will have been updated before the SSJS fires.

Comment: I'm using this code to validate a section and it is working extremely flawless in on xpage but when copied to another xpage it is breaking. I want to know why it is breaking. Also it is sound right to reinvent the working code in another xpage.

Comment: Working code somewhere != good code you should keep (it might be, but not necessarily is)

Comment: Please follow the steps to work out why it's breaking. One possibility that this will catch is if your original page has no validation but this page does.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the checkboxes, compacted the database with -c and added back those checkboxes with the same code. It is working now.